# Touch to Beam, the only way to send NFC (ICS)?

Tags: android, nfc, android-beam

I know you answered a similar question on ICS here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8320504

But there is something i still would like to know, because I'm working on my master thesis and therefore I would need this feature:

1. Is it still true, that there is no possibility  sending NFC from within an app without tap on the screen? (as it was shown in the StickyNotes sample in "How to NFC")
2. Will this great feature of NFC be available again in the future?
3. Is it true, that by disabling AndroidBeam in the settings, NFC-send-feature is disabled totally, too. You can only receive NFC?

Thank you in advance.
BTW: I'm using Android ICS 4.0.1

Comment: Slightly off topic but I believe this is a really dumb decision made by Google. During their NFC functionality presentation, they emphasized the convenience of being able to transfer data just by having two phones close together. There is no room for debate, this counter-intuitive idea of forcing the users to tap the screen destroys one of the main benefits NFC has to provide. Oh and if you lose the connectivity between the phones just because the phones were separated because the user had to flip his phone or something to tap the screen, you have to start the process all over again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Yes, it is (still) not possible to disable the UI when sharing P2P data in Android 4.0.2 and 4.0.3.
2. Google will have to decide this, I think. No way for anyone else to know.
3. Android Beam equals the "NFC-send-feature". So, yes, by disabling Android Beam in the settings, you can no longer send data via NFC. (You can still receive data, though.)

Comment: Not what I wanted to hear, but great answer - Thanks.