# Android Beam: suppress "Tab to beam"

Tags: java, android, nfc, android-beam

I have been developing an Android application which sends NDEF messages via *Android Beam* and a desktop application which receives them.

Everything works as expected; however, I personally believe that the Android Beam "Tab to beam"-screen is too circumstantial.
Is there a method to suppress this screen and simply send the data after, for instance, clicking a button?

Thanks.

Comment: No, this is not possible (unfortunately). See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/9468593/1202968

Comment: Thank you! i hate google... :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible unless you root your device. I have hacked the Nfc.apk for my Galaxy Nexus to remove the "tap to beam" UI. This is obviously very dirty and will remove the feature for every other application too.